# Java - print amount of each letter in word

Tags: java, netbeans, command-line, netbeans-8

I am practising with algorithms, and I have this problem where I have to state how many of each of the letters in the word appear. e.g. input = floor , output = f1l1o2r1. I have the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {// TODO code application logic here
        Scanner inword = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)));

        System.out.println("Enter word");
        String word = inword.nextLine();

        int length = word.length();
        char[] wordArray = word.toCharArray();
        for(int i = 0; i<length; i++){
            int count = StringUtils.countMatches(word, String.valueOf(wordArray[i]));
            System.out.print(wordArray[i] + count);
        }
    }
```

but instead I get this as output: `103109113113115` , when I enter floor as input

Comment: post the output as text, not as an image

Comment: @ChrisMowforth how exactly do you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the implementation of `StringUtils.countMatches()` is correct, the problem lies in the line

```
System.out.print(wordArray[i] + count);
```

Here, when you do `wordArray[i]`, it returns a `char`. However, doing `+count`, converts that `char` into its `ASCII` value, and adds up `count` to it.

To fix it, try doing:-

```
System.out.print(wordArray[i] + " " + count);
```

Comment: Great. Thanks. Needed the explanation

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you print out the ascii-code value of the char. Try

```
System.out.print(wordArray[i]+"" + count);
```

instead of

```
System.out.print(wordArray[i] + count);
```

Comment: I don't quite understand how that makes it work, but it really does fix my problem. thanks

Comment: You can upvote my answer or mark is as solution if you want to ;)

Comment: Won't produce the answer he says he expects - see my answer later

Answer (score 1):

First, you should use `countMatches(word, wordArray[i]);` But that will not solve the entire problem. For example, your approach would lead to an output of "f1l1o2o2r1", and for the word "boohoo", you would get "b1o4o4h1o4o4".
You need to rethink how to do it if you want the output to show the number of consecutive same letters ("b1o2h1o2"), or if you want the number of each letter, specified only once, in order of first appearance ("b1o4h1"), or the number of appearances of letters alphabetically ("b1h1o4").

Comment: You are certainly correct. However, improve your formatting. It hard to say what you are trying to present.